# best way of using cuda

Tags: cuda

There are ways of using cuda:

1. auto-paralleing tools such as PGI workstation;
2. wrapper such as Thrust(in STL style)
3. NVidia GPUSDK(runtime/driver API)

Which one is better for performance or learning curve or other factors?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Performance rankings will likely be 3, 2, 1.
Learning curve is (1+2), 3.

If you become a CUDA expert, then it will be next to impossible to beat the performance of your hand-rolled code using all the tricks in the book using the GPU SDK due to the control that it gives you.

That said, a wrapper like Thrust is written by NVIDIA engineers and shown on several problems to have 90-95+% efficiency compared with hand-rolled CUDA. The reductions, scans, and many cool iterators they have are useful for a wide class of problems too.

Auto-parallelizing tools tend to not do quite as good a job with the different memory types as karlphillip mentioned.

My preferred workflow is using Thrust to write as much as I can and then using the GPU SDK for the rest. This is largely a factor of not trading away too much performance to reduce development time and increase maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

Go with the traditional CUDA SDK, for both performance and smaller learning curve.

CUDA exposes several types of memory (global, shared, texture) which have a dramatic impact on the performance of your application, there are great articles about it on the web.

[This page](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_training.html) is very interesting and mentions the great series of articles about CUDA on [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/207200659).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the NVIDIA GPU SDK is the best, with a few caveats.  For example, try to avoid using the cutil.h functions, as these were written solely for use with the SDK, and I've personally, as well as many others, have run into some problems and bugs in them, that are hard to fix (There also is no documentation for this "library" and I've heard that NVIDIA does not support it at all)

Instead, as you mentioned, use the one of the two provided APIs.  In particular I recommend the Runtime API, as it is a higher level API, and so you don't have to worry quite as much about all of the low level implementation details as you do in the Device API.

Both APIs are fully documented in the CUDA Programming Guide and CUDA Reference Guide, both of which are updated and provided with each CUDA release.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do on the GPU. If your algorithm would highly benefit from the things thrust can offer, like reduction, prefix, sum, then thrust is definitely worth a try and I bet you can't write the code faster yourself in pure CUDA C.

However if you're porting already parallel algorithms from the CPU to the GPU, it might be easier to write them in plain CUDA C. I had already successful projects with a good speedup going this route, and the CPU/GPU code that does the actual calculations is almost identical.

You can combine the two paradigms to some extend, but as far as I know you're launching new kernels for each thrust call, if you want to have all in one big fat kernel (taking too frequent kernel starts out of the equation), you have to use plain CUDA C with the SDK.

I find the pure CUDA C actually easier to learn, as it gives you quite a good understanding on what is going on on the GPU. Thrust adds a lot of magic between your lines of code.

I never used auto-paralleing tools such as PGI workstation, but I wouldn't advise to add even more "magic" into the equation.